# Is the Weitzenböck connection the only connection with torsion, but without curvature?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, curvature, modified-gravity

In  [teleparallel gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleparallelism), the (local) connection coefficients of the Weitzenböck connection are given by

$$ \Pi^{\beta}{}_{\mu\nu}= h^{\beta}_{i} \partial_{\nu}h^{i}_{\mu} - \Gamma^{\beta}{}_{\mu\nu} \, $$

where $ \Gamma^{\beta}{}_{\mu\nu} $ is the Levi-Civita connection.

The question is:  Is there another connetion without curvature but with torsion, where the torsion is related to the curvature of the Levi-Civita connecion?

Comment: It seems there are, check this [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09008v1), where they study Deformed Weitzenböck Connections in the context of Teleparallel Gravity.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, the Weitzenböck connection is what relates torsion without having to involve curvature. Even more exotic types of theories such as $F(T,T)$ or $F(T,G)$ gravity use the Weitzenböck connection for calculations.

It is the basis of torsion based gravity models.